# How to create 2 variables in 2 rows under x-axis in barplot in r (not using ggplot)

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a clearer x-axis in bar-plot but don't know how to do. Could anyone please help?

With my current code, I'm able to draw a barplot with 2 variables in x-axis. But the value of 2 variables is standing next to each other make it unclear from reader. I want to have each row for each variable in x-axis. This is my current code and the result

My expected result will be: in the x-axis, first row is 0.1, 0.0555, etc and second row is S1-2, S2-3

```
mxCarabooda <- structure(c(13.47258, 7.430879, 13.47151, 7.53012, 14.83685, 
                           8.940968, 15.37691, 9.617533), .Dim = c(2L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
                             c("ChangeNP", "ChangeNP.1"), c("Sl-2 0.1", "S2-3 0.055", 
                                                            "S3-4 0.056", "S4-5 0.056")))
mxNeerabup <- structure(c(3.499426, 2.232676, 3.499596, 2.239664, 3.836086, 
                          2.566649, 3.995115, 2.725839), .Dim = c(2L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
                            c("ChangeNP", "ChangeNP.1"), c("Sl-2 0.01", "S2-3 0.01", 
                                                           "S3-4 0.01", "S4-5 0.02")))

mxNowergup <- structure(c(3.5135, 1.700544, 3.513586, 1.710387, 3.850266, 2.034689, 
                          4.009113, 2.194351), .Dim = c(2L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
                            c("ChangeNP", "ChangeNP.1"), c("Sl-2 0.02", "S2-3 0.01", 
                                                           "S3-4 0.02", "S4-5 0.02")))



tiff("barplot.tiff", width=260, height=100, units='mm', res=300)
par(mfrow=c(1,3), mar=c(5, 4, 4, 0.2))
colours <- c("gray63","gray87")

barplot(mxCarabooda, main='Carabooda', ylab='Profit loss ($m)',
        xlab='Change in water table at each level of GW cut', beside=TRUE, 
        col=colours, ylim=c(0,30))
legend('topright', bty="n", legend=c('Loss in GM','Loss in adjusted GM'), 
       col=c("gray63","gray87"))

barplot(mxNeerabup,main='Neerabup', ylab='', 
        xlab='Change in water table at each level of GW cut', beside=TRUE, 
        col=colours, ylim=c(0,30))
legend('topright', bty="n", legend=c('Loss in GM','Loss in adjusted GM'), 
       col=c("gray63","gray87"), pch=15)

barplot(mxNowergup,main='Nowergup', ylab='', 
        xlab='Change in water table at each level of GW cut',beside=TRUE, 
        col=colours, ylim=c(0,30))
legend('topright', bty="n", legend=c('Loss in GM','Loss in adjusted GM'), 
       col=c("gray63","gray87"), pch=15)

dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider adjusting the *names.arg* of `barplot` which defaults to names attribute of your matrix. Specifically, create new vectors of names that reverse the space-separated original `colnames` and replaces space with line breaks:

**Bar Labels**

```
barsCarabooda <- gsub(" ", "\n", 
                      lapply(strsplit(colnames(mxCarabooda), split=" "), 
                             function(x) paste(rev(x), collapse=" "))
                     )

barsNeerabup <- gsub(" ", "\n", 
                     lapply(strsplit(colnames(mxNeerabup), split=" "), 
                            function(x) paste(rev(x), collapse=" "))
                    )

barsNowergup <- gsub(" ", "\n", 
                     lapply(strsplit(colnames(mxNowergup), split=" "), 
                            function(x) paste(rev(x), collapse=" "))
                    )
```

**Plotting with `names.arg`**

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3), mar=c(5, 4, 4, 0.2))
colours <- c("gray63","gray87")

barplot(mxCarabooda, main='Carabooda', ylab='Profit loss ($m)',
        xlab='Change in water table at each level of GW cut', beside=TRUE, 
        col=colours, ylim=c(0,30), names.arg=barsCarabooda)
legend('topright', bty="n", legend=c('Loss in GM','Loss in adjusted GM'), 
       col=c("gray63","gray87"), pch=15)

barplot(mxNeerabup,main='Neerabup', ylab='', 
        xlab='Change in water table at each level of GW cut', beside=TRUE, 
        col=colours, ylim=c(0,30), names.arg=barsNeerabup)
legend('topright', bty="n", legend=c('Loss in GM','Loss in adjusted GM'), 
       col=c("gray63","gray87"), pch=15)

barplot(mxNowergup,main='Nowergup', ylab='', 
        xlab='Change in water table at each level of GW cut',beside=TRUE, 
        col=colours, ylim=c(0,30), names.arg=barsNowergup)
legend('topright', bty="n", legend=c('Loss in GM','Loss in adjusted GM'), 
       col=c("gray63","gray87"), pch=15)
```

[image: Bar Plot with Line Break X-Axis Labels]